# Iterator variable doesn't exist in IEnumerable from which it came?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a method which looks like

```
private Component[] AssociateComponentsWithParametersAndValues(
            IEnumerable<Component> components,
            IEnumerable<ComponentParameter> parameters,
            IEnumerable<ComponentParameterValue> values
            )
        {
            var componentsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Component>();
            var parametersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ComponentParameter>();
            var valuesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ComponentParameterValue>();
            foreach (Component c in components)
            {
                bool componentMatch = components.Any(co => co == c);
                bool identifierMatch = components.Any(co => co.Identifier == c.Identifier);
                if (!componentsDictionary.ContainsKey(c.Identifier))
                    componentsDictionary.Add(c.Identifier, c);
            }
            // Do a bunch of stuff to mutate the components
            return components.ToArray();
        }
```

You would think that `componentMatch` and `identifierMatch` would both be true each time right? Instead, `componentMatch` is always false and `identifierMatch` is always true. Also, the identifier is (nearly, occasionally there's some bad data) always unique, so it's not like it can be finding another component with the same identifier.

So, there must be something weird with the Component class. Well, here's what it looks like

```
public class Component : ConfigurationObject
    {
        public string Parent { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Module { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public bool? Enabled { get; set; }
        public string DBIdentifier { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, ComponentParameterAndValues> ParametersAndValues { get; set; }
        public override string Identifier => DBIdentifier;
    }
```

And here's the class it implements

```
public abstract class ConfigurationObject
    {
        public abstract string Identifier { get; }
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: @CodeCaster sure, but the current element `c` **is** contained in the collection. So the condition should be true even with reference-equality.

Comment: Yeap, must be some weird hashcoding or `==`-implementation.

Comment: I don't know every details of the codebase I'm working on, but it should just be the standard c# `==`. Is it even possible to mess with that? You can already see that the classes do nothing weird with `==`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'll try. Might take a few minutes.

Comment: well, from my persptcive `ConfigurationObject` is no "standard" c#-class... Maybe that one has some implementation for `==`?

Comment: Though.... there is multiple enumeration `components` im guessing its giving back different results

Comment: There is no "standard `==`" you can 100% implement your own. If you want to make `apple == orange` be true you can totally do that. ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/krwmST))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I could see this break, is if `IEnumerable<Component> components` is a lazily evaluated enumerable, returning new iterator objects every time. This works:

```
var list = new List<Component>
{
    new Component { Identifier = "Foo" },
    new Component { Identifier = "Bar" },
    new Component { Identifier = "Baz" },
};

foreach (Component c in list)
{
    bool componentMatch = list.Any(co => co == c);
    Console.WriteLine($"Component {c.Identifier} match: {componentMatch}");
}
```

Because `==` checks reference equality (unless `Component` overrides it, but it doesn't look like it does). However, if it's not a list, but a new result each iteration:

```
IEnumerable<Component> list = GetList();

foreach (Component c in list)
{
    bool componentMatch = list.Any(co => co == c);
    Console.WriteLine($"Component {c.Identifier} match: {componentMatch}");
}

private static IEnumerable<Component> GetList()
{
    yield return new Component { Identifier = "Foo" };
    yield return new Component { Identifier = "Bar" };
    yield return new Component { Identifier = "Baz" };
}
```

Then it prints `false`, because `foreach()` and `Any()` each get a new collection of new objects, so their references don't match.

The solution would be to enumerate once, and store the components once, materialized in a list, and use that:

```
var localComponents = components.ToList();

foreach (Component c in localComponents)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I was just coming to the same conclusion. Nice example.

Comment: Thanks guys/gals/helicopters. This is what a [mre] looks like, the rest is noise.

Comment: This was the issue. Managed to solve it in my use case by using `.ToArray()` on components, values and parameters where I call the method. This apparently forced it not to be lazily evaluated.

Comment: @RJM instead of doing it on all call sites, why not do it in the method? Or change the parameter types to `IList<T>` or `T[]` to force the caller to.

Comment: I actually only call the method once. It only exists to make another method easier to read. But I agree that that would usually be better. Anyway, thank you for figuring this out. (But I did just change the signature to only accept arrays.)